# Rewrite urls only for certain folder and remove parts of the url in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have an old project in PHP which I'm trying to modernize. The routing of the old project is just files on the server which you'd access via the url.

So for example a file placed in `folder/subfolder/file.php` would match the url `https://example.com/folder/subfolder/file.php`. Fairly standard stuff.

The new routing system would involved url rewrites where all requests are redirected to a central point (usually `index.php`) then PHP decides internally what to do with them.

Unfortunately both routing methods must exist at the same time. Deprecated legacy urls will do a `301 PERMANENT` redirect to a new url.
For example `https://example.com/shop/class/api.php` will (ideally) be redirect to `https://example.com/shop/api/v1/shop` along with any query parameters it has.

Lets assume that I have a simple folder structure like this

```
- index
   - index.php
```

All new urls should be redirected to this folder. The file priority for this folder will always be `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`.

The redirect itself is simple enough to do

```
Redirect 301 /shop/class/api.php /index/api/v1/shop
```

The next step, which I don't know how to do and my google fu isn't helping is this:

- I'd like to rewrite urls ONLY for `index` folder, otherwise the old urls won't work anymore.
- I'd like to remove the `index` part from the url and leave only the trailing part(after the redirect happens). For example `/shop/class/api.php` is redirect to `/index/api/v1/shop` after which `index` is removed and only `/api/v1/shop` remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

This is what you need.

Any request for a non existing file will be routed to this one, while existing paths and files will be replied as usual.

It is the current method to deal with a main controller file for requests with virtual urls such as what php usually does.

[mod_dir FallbackResource information page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)